# How to register users in Django while maintaining frontend bootstrap template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to register users for a multi user complaint management system using django. The frontend is already ready and I just have to do the backend. I am fairly new at django and this is my first project so I'm very confused in how to maintain the bootstrap view while being able to register users and authenticate them.
The bootstrap template is:

````
```<div class="col-lg-4 login-bg">
        <h4 class="reg-title"><strong>Get Started...</strong></h4>
        <p class="login-reg">Already have an account? <a class="log-reg-link" href="login.html">Log In </a> here</p>
        <hr>

        <form class="" action="/Dashboard/" method="post">


            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>First Name*</strong></p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-10 log-inp-field" placeholder="First Name" required>

            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Last Name*</strong></p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-10 log-inp-field" placeholder="Last Name" required>

            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Email ID*</strong></p>
            <input type="email" class="form-control col-lg-10 log-inp-field" placeholder="Enter email" required>

            <p class="reg-field-title"><strong>Password*</strong></p>
            <input type="password" class="form-control col-lg-10 log-inp-field" placeholder="Enter Password" required>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg col-lg-10 reg-btn">Register</button>
        </form>```
````

this is my accounts model:

````
```from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=130)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=130)
email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
Password = models.CharField()
````

I don't understand what to do? What to put in the views and the forms?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! could you please elaborate what you mean by `how to maintain the bootstrap view`.

Comment: like what I mean is not change the css view? if that makes sense... But how to register users while maintaining how the frontend looks

Comment: What should i add in the template to do that?

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use `AJAX` [docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). You can make [API calls](https://rapidapi.com/blog/api-glossary/api-call/) to your backend on press of the login button and authenticate the user without needing to POST to another route.

Or you can use [entend](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extends-django-template-tags/) to not repeat HTML in different templates.

Answer (score 0):

create the view that handles the registration, it's going to be a view that handles a form:

view.py :( this  a standart exemple from the documentation )

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

in the template :

name.html :

```
<div class="col-lg-4 login-bg">
        <h4 class="reg-title"><strong>Get Started...</strong></h4>
        <p class="login-reg">Already have an account? <a class="log-reg-link" href="login.html">Log In </a> here</p>
        <hr>

        <form class="" action="/Dashboard/" method="post">


           {{form}}

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg col-lg-10 reg-btn">Register</button>
        </form>
```

form is a **context** it's the result of your view and you send it to the template, then render it with the Django template language {{form}} you can read more about this: [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/)
Django also provide a default Auth system and if you don't like it there a package called **django allauth** it's one of the best auth system, there is you can just follow a tutorial on YouTube for Django default Auth or Jango all-out it's easy